# Accessing viewport center region from view and change the activeItem

Tags: extjs

I am trying to get the reference of viewport -> center region from the ToolBarView, When clicked on logout button in toolbar, center region in viewport card0 should be set as activeItem. Please anybody help me.

//View

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ToolBarView', {

    extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
    xtype: 'bottom-toolbar',
    alias: 'widget.toolBar',
    height: 40,    
    items: [
            {
                xtype: 'tbfill'
            },
            {
                text: 'Home'
            },
            { 
                xtype: 'tbseparator'                        
            },

            {

                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Settings',
                scale: 'medium',
                menu: [{
                        text:'My Profile'
                    },{
                        text:'Change Password'
                    },{
                        text:'View Options'
                    }]

            },
            {
                xtype: 'tbseparator'
            },
            {
                text: 'Logout',
                 handler: function() {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Are you sure you want to logout??');
                    tex = button.up('toolbar'),//here i need to change viewport activeItem
                    tex.close()//close this toolbar view and logout and show loginView(card 0)
                }
            }               
            ]   

});


//My Viewport is
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    layout: 'border',       
    requires: [
        'MyApp.view.LoginView',
        'MyApp.view.GridView',
        'MyApp.view.RegisterForm',
        'MyApp.view.TabView',       
        'MyApp.view.ToolBarView'        
    ],           
    items: [
    {
        region: 'north',
        border: false,      
        items:[
            {   xtype: 'image',
                src: 'images/logo.jpg',
                width:200,
                height:63
            }           
            ]
    },
    {
        region: 'south',
        html: 'Hello',
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        height: 25

    },
    {
        region: 'center',
        layout: 'card',
        activeItem: 0,

        items:
            [{

                id: 'card0',
                xtype: 'container',
                items:[ {xtype: 'loginView'}],
                region: 'center',               

                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'center',
                    pack: 'center'
                }
             },
             {
                id: 'card1',
                xtype: 'container',
                items:[ {xtype: 'registerForm'}],
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'center',
                    pack: 'center'
                }

            },
            {
                items:[
                    {xtype: 'toolBar'},// this is the toolbar from which i need to access viewport and change the activeItem
                    {xtype: 'gridView'},
                    {xtype: 'tabView'}
                 ]
            }]
    }]

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to set a card dynamically you will want to use the [`setActiveTab`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-method-setActiveTab) (please note it appears `setActiveItem` will work to but it isn't documented.) method on the [`tabpanel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel) component.

I'd recommending adding an `itemId` to the tabpanel to make it easy to query or else you will want move up or down from the button in the click event listener/handler.

`Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myItemId')[0].setActiveTab(0);`

[And here is a fiddle that shows a working example.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/dfp)

And the code from the fiddle for reference on this site:

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel',{
            renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
            title:'My Tab Panel',
            itemId:'myTabPanel',
            tbar:['->',{
                text:'Logout',
                handler:function(btn){
                    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myTabPanel')[0].setActiveTab(0);
                }
            }],
            items:[{
                title:'Tab 1',
                html:'<h1>First Tab</h1>'
            },{
                title:'Tab 2',
                html:'<h1>Second Tab</h2>'
            }]
        });
```